# How to generate series of Strings like a1, a2, a3 a4 ....in R

Tags: string, r, character, paste

How to generate a strings like a1, a2, a3...
I tried:
    paste("a",1:3)
    [1] "a 1" "a 2" "a 3"

But I dont want space in it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to `paste` and `paste0` there is also `sprintf` which can give more control of formatting:

```
> sprintf("a%d", 1:5)
[1] "a1" "a2" "a3" "a4" "a5"
> sprintf("a%d", 1:15)
 [1] "a1"  "a2"  "a3"  "a4"  "a5"  "a6"  "a7"  "a8"  "a9"  "a10" "a11" "a12"
[13] "a13" "a14" "a15"
> sprintf("a%02d", 1:15)
 [1] "a01" "a02" "a03" "a04" "a05" "a06" "a07" "a08" "a09" "a10" "a11" "a12"
[13] "a13" "a14" "a15"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `paste0(...)` or `paste(..., sep = "")`.  The default for `paste` is to insert the space.

Answer (score 2):

```
> paste0("a", 1:3)
## [1] "a1" "a2" "a3"
```